# Join table on unmatched column data

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two table **Person** and **Account**. and tables contains records as follows,

Person

```
----------------------------------------
Slno     Name      Phone       Acc_type
----------------------------------------
1       Robert    211211      0
2       Mia       332332      35001
```

Account

```
----------------------------------------
Acc_type    Acc_Desc
----------------------------------------
35001       Regular  
35002       non-Regular
```

I'm trying to fetch record details based on **Slno** whick is primary key. I have written query as follows,

```
Select P.Slno,P.Name,P.Phone,P.Acc_type,A.Acc_Desc 
From   Person P
Join   Account A
On     A.Acc_type = P.Acc_type
Where  P.Slno = '2'
```

for the above query i'm getting following output

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Slno     Name      Phone       Acc_type    Acc_Desc
-----------------------------------------------------
2       Mia       332332      35001        Regular
```

but there is Acc_type in Account table which is given for **Slno 1** but getting no records.
i need to fetch output as follows, is that possible

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Slno     Name      Phone       Acc_type    Acc_Desc
-----------------------------------------------------
1       Robert    211211      0
```

What chages in the query will make this output possible.

Comment: You need both the rows???

Comment: No i'm fetching row based on Slno passed

Comment: `Acc_type = 0` is not there in the `Account` table

Comment: correct but i have previously entered some records with Acc_type  0 in Person Table.

Comment: `Acc_type=0` means what?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.Slno,P.Name,P.Phone,P.Acc_type,A.Acc_Desc
FROM Person P 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Account A ON A.Acc_type = P.Acc_type
```

Comment: This is a outer join, so it will consider all the tuples. Outer joins are for finding records that may not have a match in the other table. As such, you have to specify which side of the join is allowed to have a missing record. In this case, Acc_Desc has to appear which is present in the second table. Hence, we use a RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d657a/1)

**Oracle 11g Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
  Slno INT,
  Name VARCHAR2(20),
  Phone INT,
  Acc_type INT
);

INSERT INTO Person
SELECT 1, 'Robert', 211211, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Mia',    332332, 35001 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Account (
  Acc_type INT,
  Acc_Desc VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO Account
SELECT 35001, 'Regular' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 35002, 'non-Regular'FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT P.*,
       A.Acc_Desc
FROM   Person p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       Account a
       ON  (p.acc_type = a.acc_type )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d657a/1/0)**:

```
| Slno |   Name |  Phone | Acc_type | Acc_Desc |
|------|--------|--------|----------|----------|
|    2 |    Mia | 332332 |    35001 |  Regular |
|    1 | Robert | 211211 |        0 |   (null) |
```

Answer (score -1):

Try left/right join. Here is how does it works http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Edit cuz of form:

In your case it would look like this:

```
 
Select P.Slno,P.Name,P.Phone,P.Acc_type,A.Acc_Desc 
From   Person P
Left Join   Account A
On     A.Acc_type = P.Acc_type
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no account type 0 in the account table so the join will filter it out.

Comment: This should be a comment.